# How to next next and previous ids in an ordered search when on a specific id? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have an MLS site that you can search and it gives you a list of results.  I then store the mysql string in a session.

When you click on a result you go to the page listed by its property MLS number.

From that page I have a forward and backward button that is supposed to go back and forth through properties.

How do I use that same stored query string to find the next result and previous result depending on what property I am looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the results are ordered by id, you could modify the stored query like this:

```
WHERE id > current_id LIMIT 1
```

to get the next property, where current_id is the id of the currently viewed record, and likewise:

```
WHERE id < current_id LIMIT 1
```

to get the previous one.